# Access token obtained from Auth0 by front-end not working against backend Web API, when using Auth0 custom domain

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0

We have an Angular 10 front-end web app, with a .Net 6 back-end Web API. We are using Auth0 as the Authentication Provider.

We’ve been having some clients complain (mainly on Safari browser) that they cannot log onto our app due to cross-site tracking being disabled. If we enable it for the user, then it works. Obviously, this isn't an acceptable solution. I read that this happens because Auth0 is on a different domain than the web app, and that using an Auth0 custom domain would help, as we could make it that our front-end, back-end and Auth0 are all on the same domain - no more crossing domain boundaries. So we upgraded to a paid Auth0 license, and activated custom domain.

However, when the user logs into our app now, and the user is forwarded to the Auth0 log in page (using the new custom domain), the access token received by the front-end from Auth0 doesn't seem to work, as when the front-end tries to call the API using this token, it receives a 401 Unauthorized response.

As far as I can see, nothing needed to be changed on the back-end API when we switched to using Auth0 custom domain. The only change that was required was on the front-end Angular app, where we had to update the “domain” to point to the new custom domain.

I also whitelisted the new custom domain URL on Auth0's “allowed callback URL”, “allowed logout URL” and “allowed web origins”, just in case.

Also, I did try updating the "Authority" option of services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer() to the new Auth0 custom domain too, on the API:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/"; 
            options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:Audience"];
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I updated Auth0:Domain in appsettings.json to refer to the new Auth0 custom domain. But it made no difference.

Any idea why the front-end receives a 401 Unauthorized response from our API whenever it tries to call it, if using the custom Auth0 domain? (but works fine when using the non-custom Auth0 domain)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you call the auth0 management api?

Comment: Are you seeing an encrypted token or a JWT?

Comment: Hi Chen, thanks for the message. I am not calling the Auth0 Management API. The front-end web app is calling the back-end web api, that's about it. Yes, the front-end is obtaining an access token from Auth0 after the user successfully logs in, but that access token appears to be invalid as when the front-end uses it to call the the back-end web api, the api returns a 401 Unauthorized response. However, if the front-end does NOT use the Auth0 custom domain, then the access token it obtains from Auth0 works just fine against the back-end api.

Comment: This can be due to a change in issuer claim inside the access token. Try adding this line: `options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = Configuration[“Auth0:Issuer”];`. And in appsetting: `“Issuer”: “[CUSTOM_DOMAIN]”, (i.e. https://login.mycustomdomain.com/)`.

Comment: Thanks Chen. Just to be sure, if my custom domain is auth.propworx.co.za, my issuer will be https://login.auth.propworx.co.za/?
Also, for Authority/Domain, should I use the custom domain, or the non-custom domain? 
Thanks

Comment: It depends on your custom domain, you can try it. @Fabricio Rodriguez